# iframeで読み込まれる側のページのリファラーは、常に読み込む側のページとなる？

Tags: php, html5

iframeで読み込まれる側のページに、PHPで

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

と記述した場合、取得できる値は、常にiframeを読み込む側のページとなるのでしょうか？

・例えばブックマーク経由でアクセスした場合でも、常にリファラーを取得可能？
・ブラウザ間に差異はない？
・ここら辺の仕様はどこで定義されているのでしょうか？